# AngularJS. Уникальное имя поля

Tags: angularjs

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно поля формы называть всегда по разному, при каждой загрузке страницы.

Сейчас подобный код:

```
<input autocomplete="off" type="text" name="name" ng-model="model.LastName" required>
<div ng-show="form.name.$invalid && form.name.$dirty">
    error
</div>
```

Пытался давать имена типа `name{{unique}}` и `name[{{unique}}]` - тогда не показывается блок после инпута. Как можно реализовать такое поведение?

Заранее благодарен.

**UPDATE**

js (директива):

```
app.directive('fioData', [function () {
return {
    templateUrl: '/path/to/fioForm.html',
    replace: false,
    transclude: true,
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
        model: '=',
        formId: '@',
    },
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
    }
};
}]);
```

html:

```
<div fio-data model="Data.Applicant" form-id="applicant"></div>
```

Comment: добавьте содержимое '/path/to/fioForm.html' и пример данных которые вы передаете

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `name{{unique}}` а в ng-show такую конструкцию:

```
form['name' + unique].$invalid
```

Comment: Не срабатывает. Возможно от версии angular зависит? У меня 1.2.х. И, возможно, важное уточнение, это происходит в `template` директивы.

Comment: @A1essandro, добавьте в вопрос пример вашей директивы и как вы ее используете

Comment: От версии не зависит точно. Если у вас все работает без unique, но перестает работать с ним, то скорей всего вы не передали unique.